# C# WPF TextBox into webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm really new to C# and I'm just messing around a bit now. I use the WPF application and I'm now trying to fill in the text that I typed into a textbox into a textbox inside the webbrowser.

So basically there is a TextBox inside the webbrowser(like the search bar on google or something) and then there is the TextBox that I set up in visual studio. I type in something and then click a button. I want the thing that I typed in to appear in the textbox  on the webbrowser.

I tried this line, but this is from Windows Forms and it appears that this command doesn't exist inside WPF, however I really want to use WPF because for school I'm supposed to master this application:

WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("id").SetAttribute("value", TextBox.Text);

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hello DrRonne: Are the TextBox, Button and WebBrowser all defined in a XAML/WPF Control, Window or page?

Comment: Yes, all of these are defined, they are in a XAML.